# How can forward user's message to a channel after replying? pyTelegramBot Api

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I can't get a way for the bot to forward the original message of a user reply to a channel

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["data"])
def info(message):
    markup = ForceReply()
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Info", reply_markup= markup)
    text = message.text
    bot.send_message(id_channel , text, reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have selected wrong `message` as `text`. The `text` variable here stores the `/data` command, not the channel post.
If the user sends channel post with the command in same message, try:

```
from telebot import *
@bot.message_handler(commands=["data"])
def info(message):
    markup = ForceReply()
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Info", reply_markup= markup)
    text = util.extract_argument(message.text)
    bot.send_message(id_channel , text, reply_markup=markup)
#________OR__________
@bot.message_handler(commands=["data"])
def info(message):
    markup = ForceReply()
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Info", reply_markup= markup)
    text = message.text.strip('/data')
    bot.send_message(id_channel , text, reply_markup=markup)
```

If the user sends the channel post after the /data command, try:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["data"])
def info(message):
    markup = ForceReply()
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please send the channel post", reply_markup= markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, handle_post)
def handle_post(message):
    text = message.text
    bot.send_message(id_channel , text, reply_markup=markup)
```

If you are trying to send the same message to both user and channel, try:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["data"])
def info(message):
    markup = ForceReply()
    text  = "Info"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_markup= markup)
    bot.send_message(id_channel , text, reply_markup=markup)
```